# Heroku "Please install the postgresql adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to use the free hosting that heroku uses. I tried many many options and I still keep getting this error "Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install..." on the heroku log.

First of all, I got the same error almost 1 year ago, I was expecting heroku to fix this by now.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Here is my GEMFILE:

```
  1 source 'https://rubygems.org'
  2
  3 gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
  4
  5 # Bundle edge Rails instead:
  6 # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
  7
  8 gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
  9 gem 'typhoeus'
 10
 11 # Gems used only for assets and not required
 12 # in production environments by default.
 13 group :assets do
 14   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 15   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 16   gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
 17   # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 18   # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
 19
 20   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 21 end
 22
 23 group :development do
 24   gem 'debugger'
 25 end
 26
 27 group :development, :test do
 28   gem 'capybara'
 29   gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
 30   gem 'factory_girl'
 31   gem 'mysql2'
 32 end
 33
 34 group :test do
 35   gem 'vcr'
 36 end
 37
 38 group :production do
 39   gem 'pg'
 40 end
 41
 42 gem 'proxylocal'
 43
 44 gem 'devise'
 45 gem 'jquery-rails'
 46 gem 'turbolinks'
```

and my config/database.yml file:

```
  1 # MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
  2 #
  3 # Install the MYSQL driver
  4 #   gem install mysql2
  5 #
  6 # Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
  7 #   gem 'mysql2'
  8 #
  9 # And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
 10 #   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
 11 development:
 12   adapter: postgresql
 13   encoding: utf8
 14   reconnect: false
 15   database: resource-management_development
 16   pool: 5
 17   username: root
 18   password:
 19   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
 20
 21 # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
 22 # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
 23 # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
 24 test: &test
 25   adapter: postgresql
 26   encoding: utf8
 27   reconnect: false
 28   database: resource-management_test
 29   pool: 5
 30   username: root
 31   password:
 32   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
 33
 34 production:
 35   adapter: postgresql
 36   encoding: utf8
 37   reconnect: false
 38   database: resource-management_production
 39   pool: 5
 40   username: root
 41   password:
 42   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
 43
 44 cucumber:
 45   <<: *test
```

Here is the full error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-a
dapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

Can somebody get it solved, so me and loads of people can deploy on this god-forsaken platform heroku?

PS: you might notice that I have a " gem 'mysql2'" in the  development, that is because I got this from another solution here. It doesn't work without it anyway.

Comment: I believe you have to use `gem 'pg'` instead of this one you are using.

Comment: Don't specify mysql socket with postgresql configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a production group in your database.yml if you are using Heroku. To get the database to work in production, you will need to run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

To use this locally, check out this setup: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup

Change your test and development configurations if you are using mysql, although I would recommend having all three environments use the same database system.

Comment: I am on a free account, can I do what you said?

Comment: I haven't used the local setup article personally, but the configuration steps I gave are what work for me, and I have a free account. Like, rony36 stated, I also don't think you need activerecord adapter gem.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3 You have to use the gem `pg`. So maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @rony36 Oh, didn't saw that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using this `gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'` in 8th line of the `gemfile`. Did you tried by removing this line?